# Flutter pageController jumpToPage with Charts Flutter causes setState called after dispose

Tags: flutter

I am using BottomNavigation with PageView and Charts Flutter (charts_flutter: ^0.6.0). I realise if I use pageController.jumpToPage(index), it will cause the error setState() called after dispose(): BaseChartState. If I change to pageController.animateToPage, occasionally it will produce the error.

I have used if(mounted) before setState but is does not help.

pubspec.yaml:
charts_flutter: ^0.6.0

home.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'page1.dart';
import 'page2.dart';
import 'page3.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
  }

}

class _HomeState extends State<Home>{

  //PageController pageController;
  int currentBottomNavIndex = 0;

  onTapped(int index) {

    setState(() {
      currentBottomNavIndex = index;
      pageController.jumpToPage(index);
      //pageController.animateToPage(index, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    });
  }

  PageController pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
    //keepPage: false,
    keepPage: true,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    pageController.dispose();
  }

  Widget buildPageView() {



    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        Page1(),
        Page2(),
        Page3(),
      ],
    );
  }

  void pageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentBottomNavIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),

      //body: bottomNav[currentBottomNavIndex],
      body: buildPageView(),

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTapped,
        currentIndex: currentBottomNavIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text("Page1"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
            title: Text('Page2'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Text("Page3"),
          ),
        ],
      ),

    );

  }

}
```

Page1 and Page2 is normal text. Page 3 is the Pie Chart.

When I click from Page3 -> Page 2 or Page1. I will get the following error:

Error result:

flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
flutter: setState() called after dispose(): BaseChartState#64182(lifecycle state: defunct, not
flutter: mounted, tickers: tracking 0 tickers)
flutter: This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in
flutter: the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error
flutter: can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The preferred solution
flutter: is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another
flutter: solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the
flutter: object is still in the tree.
flutter: This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is
flutter: retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory
flutter: leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().

**Update:**

I have placed if(mounted) in my dart file and I guess it is the wrong place. I edited the package file base_chart_state.dart line 72:

```
@override
void requestRebuild() {
if(mounted) setState(() {});
}
```

After adding if(mounted), it solves the problem.